# Composer Require Differences

Tags: php, composer-php, dependency-management

I am just starting to learn about Composer, the PHP package manager. What are the differences between installing a dependency between these three commands?

composer require doctrine/dbal

composer require doctrine/dbal:2.*

composer require doctrine/dbal:2.0.0

Comment: There's a [long explanation](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/versions.md) that'd I'd recommend reading. For your examples, the first is "I want DBAL, figure out the rest for me", the second is "I want DBAL version 2.something, figure out what works" and the last is "I want DBAL at one very specific version"

Comment: Have you tried running these commands to check for differences?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will find the detailed answer here:
https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/versions.md

The first will try install any version of doctrine/dbal package.
Second will try install one of the versions 2.
Third will try install version 2.0.0

Comment: Will the first command install the latest version of the package?

Comment: Yes. You would usually not require to specify the version in `require` command for that reason.

Comment: The latest possible to install according to constraints of other packages in your project

Comment: It is also helpful to know the difference between the command line and the JSON file, too. When you run `composer require doctrine/dbal`, the CLI will find the best version and then put that specific version number as `^` constraint in the JSON, so it might say `"doctrine/dbal": "^2.0.1"`. The JSON file also has an option for `*` meaning any version which is _not_ the same as the CLI's missing version.

Comment: Per Arek's comment, is it possible for a package to put a version constraint on another package? How?

Comment: @GTSJoe, yes, that is the role of `composer.json` file. Here's [one from Symfony](https://github.com/symfony/dotenv/blob/5.x/composer.json) where they say `"symfony/deprecation-contracts": "^2.1"`. If you had a hard requirement on version 2.0 with no upgrades, composer would not let you install that package

Comment: go to the vendor dir and check one of the packages. A composer.json file inside will be similar to your project composer.json file. You will find `require` section there as well.

Comment: @ChrisHaas So if I had "symfony/deprecation-contracts": "^2.1 in my composer.json, what would happen if I ran: composer require symfony/deprecation-contracts:3.0.0? Would I get an error?

Comment: I don't know why this is down-voted, this is the correct answer. @GTSJoe, yes. If you [check the docs](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/versions.md#caret-version-range-) for the `^` operator, `^1.2.3` is equivalent to `>=1.2.3 <2.0.0`